# Multiple issues while setting up 2 rows of cards

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[What I'm trying to replicate (Figma)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBaH.png)

[What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0neit.png)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/8bitmd/pen/wvQNWVO)

Two of the problems I'm facing are that the rating for each card isn't at the bottom of the card like Figma's design but directly below the subtitle, and the titles for the 3rd and 5th card aren't on a single line, even though they look like they have plenty of space to do so. For this project I have to use Flexbox only, no CSS grid.

```html
<div class="hebergements-cards">
<article class="card-vertical">
                            <img  src="images/hebergements/nicate-lee.jpg" alt="Image de la chambre d'hôtel montrant deux lits">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="card-txt">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">Auberge Le Panier</h3>
                                        <p class="card-subtitle">Nuit à partir de 23<span class="euro">€</span></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-rating">
                                    <i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-star neutral-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Note de 4 sur 5</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>

</div>
```

```css
.hebergements-cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 30px;
}

.hebergements-cards .card-vertical {
    margin-top: 33px;
}

.hebergements-cards .card-content {
    width: 67%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hebergements-cards .card-title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.hebergements-cards .card-subtitle {
    margin: 0;
}

.card-rating {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-vertical {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 33%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.card-vertical img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
    width: 100%;
    height: 124px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Understood, sorry about that. I'll edit the question in a moment.

Comment: There's hundreds of ways to snap an element to bottom and hundreds of reasons why the line wraps. if you could make a simple live html css snippet here, we could investigate

Comment: Added CodePen. I don't know if it's enough or too much. I'm new here, still learning the ropes!

Comment: @8bitmd set the card title width to 100% make sure every card has its own width

Comment: Changing the card-content width fixed it... still don't know why it was 67%. Thank you all for your help, that's an issue I could have easily avoided by inspecting the page a bit more. Narayan, my CSS is messy because I started learning less than 2 weeks ago

Comment: I've updated the answer doesn't need to use 100% to title if you want you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part of CSS

```
.card-vertical .card-title {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        width: 100%
    
    }

.hebergements-cards .card-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was with the card-content.